# Ubuntu hangs at purple screen after using sudo reboot

Tags: lubuntu

I just tried `sudo reboot`, and after that it restarted and showed the dual boot option. On choosing Ubuntu, it freezes to purple screen only. I am on using Ubuntu 16.04.

I tried to restart again, but same result.

**Edit**

I have installed `shiny-server` and set the configuration by the following commands

```
sudo /opt/shiny-server/bin/deploy-example default
sudo /opt/shiny-server/bin/deploy-example user-dirs
```

after these commands, I did `sudo reboot`.

Comment: Please describe what did you do *before* rebooting.

Comment: Just tried some commands to set directory for server

Comment: Right! Please edit your question and post those commands. Whatever happened has to do with what you did before rebooting and nothing to do with how you rebooted and with whether or not you have a dual boot. Consider this and edit your question accordingly, focusing in what is relevant and editing out what isn't.